# Automatic form submission if textfield or localstorage contains data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

i want to perform an automatic login function. i've got the script that does save email and password on the localstorage for the first time a user logs in and also displays the email and password the subseqents times the user opens the app in their respective textfields (email and password)

```
$(function() {
  var
    $email = $('#email'),
    $password = $('#password');

  // SAVE VARIABLES TO LOCAL STORAGE
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("eaddress", $email.val());
    localStorage.setItem("pwd", $password.val());
  });

  // IF EMAIL AND PASSWORD ARE SAVED, PREPOPULATE THE FORM FIELDS
  if (localStorage.getItem("eaddress") != null) {
    $email.val(localStorage.getItem("eaddress"));
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("pwd") != null) {
    $password.val(localStorage.getItem("pwd"));
  }
});
```

MY HTML

```
<form action="login_script.asp" method="post" name="form5" target="_parent" id="form5" onclick="save()" >
            <table width="270" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>

                  <input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="40"/></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Password</strong></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40"/></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;

                  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                  &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><span style="width: 480px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;"><img src="imgs/loader.gif" alt="" name="gif" id="gif" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 30px; visibility: hidden;" /></span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#form5').submit(function() {
    $('#gif').css('visibility', 'visible');
    return true;
});
            </script>
```

Now what i want to achieve is there should be an automatic submission once there is data in the localstorage or the email and password textfields contains some variables

i got the script on a research that does auto form submission but don't know how to fuse it into mine

```
$(function(){

$("input[name=name]").val("somename");
$("input[name=email]").val("323@ds.com");
$('#aweberform').submit();

});

<input type="submit" name="someothername" value="click to submit!">
```

Comment: what `checkReachability()` is doing?

Comment: it's a function i was it to check for internet connectivity. let me clear it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function() {
  var
    $email = $('#email'),
    $password = $('#password'),
    localEmail = localStorage.getItem("eaddress"),
    localPwd = localStorage.getItem("pwd");

  // IF EMAIL AND PASSWORD ARE SAVED PREVIOUSLY, POPULATE THE FORM FIELDS THEN SUBMIT FORM

  // check if email saved previously
  if (localEmail != null) {        
    $email.val(localEmail);
  }

  // check if password saved previously
  if (localPwd != null) {
    $password.val(localPwd);
  }

  // if both exist in localstorage, submit form
  if (localPwd != null && localPwd != null) {
     $('form').submit();
  }

  // SAVE VARIABLES TO LOCAL STORAGE
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("eaddress", $email.val());
    localStorage.setItem("pwd", $password.val());
  });

});
```

Comment: the preloader loads like its performing a login action but doesn't submit. i'm editing the question to add my html